# Find the vertices of a convex polytope described by a system of linear inequalities

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-geometry, polytopes

Given a $m\times n$ real number matrix $A$ and a $m\times 1$ real number matrix $a$. $Ax\le a$ describes a polytope. Is there a simple way to express the vertices or extremal points of this polytope?

Comment: Short answer, no.  Longer answer, your can search for these points by using a linear tableau as we do in solving a linear program (LP) by the simplex method.  You are working in $n$ dimensional space, so these points are at the intersections of $n$ or more subspaces represented by the "rows" of $Ax = a$.  I think a very similar Question was asked in the past week here.  Let me try to find it.

Comment: I cannot find a recent such Question, so perhaps I came across an older one in the course of reviewing posts.  In any case see the Wikipedia article [Vertex Enumeration Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem).